# GraphQL Fields Undefined

Tags: node.js, graphql, graphql-js

Starting out with a GraphQL / Node / Express / Typescript stack, I am coming across an issue where field arguments are not being passed to the resolver function. I have two queries:

UserList:

```
UserList: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        args: {
            userName: {
                type: GraphQLString
            },
            userIsLocked: {
                type: GraphQLBoolean
            },
            userIsConfirmed: {
                type: GraphQLBoolean
            },
            userAwaitingPassword: {
                type: GraphQLBoolean
            }
        },
        resolve: ((_, {fields}) => new User().where({fields}))
    }
```

And User:

```
User: {
    type: UserType,
    args: {
        userId: {
            type: GraphQLID
        }
    },
    resolve: ((_, {userId}) => new User().getById({userId}))
}
```

The `User().where()` function defaults to displaying all users if no criteria is provided. However, consider the following query and results:

```
query All {
  UserList(userIsLocked:true){
    userId
    userName
    userIsLocked
  }
}

// Results
{
  "data": {
    "UserList": [
      {
        "userId": "a4f1d968-52d6-4148-bf62-1e132a4defde",
        "userName": "user1",
        "userIsLocked": false
      },
      {
        "userId": "b42a1170-096a-11e9-b568-0800200c9a66",
        "userName": "administrator",
        "userIsLocked": false
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Obviously, userIsLocked is not being passed the fields argument on the `where()` function. However, the following works:

```
query Individual {
  User(userId: "a4f1d968-52d6-4148-bf62-1e132a4defde") {
    userId
    userName
    userIsLocked
  }
}

// Results
{
  "data": {
    "User": {
      "userId": "a4f1d968-52d6-4148-bf62-1e132a4defde",
      "userName": "user1",
      "userIsLocked": false
    }
  }
}
```

When `userId` is logged on a request to `getById()`, I see `{"userId":"a4f1d968-52d6-4148-bf62-1e132a4defde"}` in the console. But when `fields` is logged on a request to `where()`, all that shows in the console is `undefined` and my query defaults to displaying all users. I can not figure out why 2 apparently equal queries would be behaving in such different ways. I have scoured the documentation for GraphQL but all I can find are sample queries and general query structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument passed to the `resolve` function is an object the properties of which map to the arguments for that field. Let's look at the working resolver:

```
resolve: (_, {userId}) => new User().getById({userId})
```

Here, you're using [object destructuring syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Setting_a_function_parameter's_default_value) to unpack the `userId` property from the second parameter and sign it to a variable of the same name. You then use [shorthand property name syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to create an object with the `userId` property (with the value of the `userId` variable you defined) and this object is passed to the `getById` method.

This is syntactically equivalent to the following function:

```
resolve: (_, args) => {
  const userId = args.userId
  return new User().getById({ userId: userId })
}
```

It's unclear from your question what ORM you're using, so I can't speak to whether you're correctly calling the `where` method in other resolver. However, you are definitely not unpacking any of the arguments for that field. Here's your function:

```
resolve: (_, {fields}) => new User().where({fields})
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
resolve: (_, args) => {
  const fields = args.fields
  return new User().where({ fields: fields })
}
```

Your field has the following four arguments: `userName`, `userIsLocked`, `userIsConfirmed` and `userAwaitingPassword`. `fields` is not a valid argument and therefore will always be undefined unless you add an argument named fields to your `UserList` field and actually pass it in. I'm going to hazard a guess and say your model also doesn't have a `fields` property. If you simply want to pass in the arguments object to the `where` method, you can do:

```
resolve: (_, fields) => new User().where(fields)
```

Note the lack of curly braces. Again, you haven't told us anything about what ORM you're using or the User model itself, so this still may not give you the desired results if you're not correctly using *that* API. However, hopefully this puts you on the right track.

Comment: That was it. After removing the braces I saw that it was actually feeding an object with those keys.